# Union shapes which is not touching

Tags: arcobjects, union

I want to union two shapes which are not touching each other using ArcObjects.

I do not want to perform small buffer on two shapes and union them. This is because when we apply buffer round buffer 0.002 it creates lot of additional vertices.

This is very much custom requirement. Please help me how to proceed on this.

Comment: I don't understand how you can union two shapes which do not intersect/touch. Is that not a requirement of a union? See http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_commonly_used_tools

Comment: sgrieve: I agree. This is the business requirement. Say we have two adjacent parcels (complex polygon with more vertices and exclusions) belong to same person - we want to union and make it as one single shape. These two adjacent polygons are created using map objects hence they do not touch because of accuracy issues. Now we have union them as one single shape. This is not basic union operation rather custom one. But how to achieve it?

Comment: Sounds like you want to 'merge', but this will generally create a multi-part feature.  I think you should specify what exactly you intend to do with the geometry between the 2 polys...single shape and single feature do not mean the same thing.

Comment: Is there a common attribute in these two parcel features? Have you tried running Merge on them, like T.Wayne has suggested above?

Comment: Thanks to both.We have two shapes which is adjacent to each other which is not touching . We want to merge as one single feature(not shape).We need to do spatial operation only not attribute feature. Result should be singe part feature.

Comment: Do you have many polygons to merge?  I.e., can you do it manually in an edit session using the Merge command? Or are you looking for some form of automation? Just an FYI, when you create multipart features from single part, you share attributes so you will lose unique attributes of each part.  You will have to pick which part you want the multipart feature to pull attributes from. If you absolutely have to do this through ArcObjects, I'm not sure how to do it programmatically if you can't use attributes to decide things.

Comment: a diagram would help everyone to provide a good answer..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. Aggreggate Polygon tool is one which am looking for. This tool aggregate the polygon based on the distance.